# I cant push using aws codecommit. my changes dont show up

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

i get the following error when i git pull from an aws repo using codecommit:

`git fetch fatal: Failed to write item to store. [0x6c6] fatal: The array bounds are invalid`
git commit works
but after a git push my changes dont persist on the remote repo

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a similar error. However, in my case the commits were working just fine, but I was getting the following error message all the time:

> fatal: Failed to write item to store. [0x6c6]

> fatal: The array bounds are invalid

### My context

1. Using git-credential-manager from MS because I have a lot of Azure DevOps git repos.
2. But still needing an occasional CodeCommit repo. In this case, I need to make sure the git-credential-manager is not invoked when I run git commands on a CodeCommit repo.
3. I happen to be using AWS sso (now known as IAM Identity Center) to authenticate to CodeCommit, not an IAM user.

My Usual use of GCM was the point of failure for me (your context may be different). Basically, it seems like CodeCommit repos need to be told not to even try a GCM call, by removing GCM as a credential helper for this repo.

### Solution

Set this git repo to *NOT* have GCM as a helper. (See some discussion at [this AWS forum post](https://repost.aws/questions/QU08el9XbJT4q8cZEwpmHhIw/codecommit-git-windows-fatal-failed-to-write-item-to-store-0x6c6), I'm indebted to Simon Heather for pointing out the best wey to do this).

`git config credential.helper ""`

The error message goes away.

### Details of my configuration

- Win11
- Git version 2.39.1.windows.1
- Git GCM version 2.0.886+ea93cb5158
- AWS git-remote-codecommit 1.16

Answer (score 1):

Hi All I was also facing the same issue, in my case we have AWS federated access account. Where I was using below commands for cloning.
Due to this I am also facing error in Visual Studio 2019 while pull and push.

**Command**

git clone codecommit::us-east-1://myrepository

**Error**

Cloning into 'myrepository'...

fatal: Failed to write item to store. [0x6c6]

fatal: The array bounds are invalid

**Solution**

I took the latest version of The "Git Credential manager for Window" exe, from this URL
https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases
after installing the "Git Credential manager for Window"
now set

Open visual studio-> tools-> options->Source control-> Git global setting -> credentials helper-> GCM for Windows.

this resolve the issue for me.